# Having issues referencing a class with NUnit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, nunit

I have a directory labeled unit-testing-using-nunit as defined in the Microsoft documentation. My issue is being unable to reference the classes I want to test. I'm still relatively new to .NET so I'm having issues understanding how to properly implement these unit tests.

[image: This is my directory tree]

After implementing Usings.cs
[image: Usings.cs]

I end up with this error:
[image: Error]

I feel like once I get a hint for how to reference /API/Entities/AppUser.cs I'll be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to add a project reference in `Entities.Tests.csproj` to the API project like so:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\API\API.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```